# Stack Exchange chat via Pidgin, Empathy, etc?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Is there any way to connect to Stack Exchange chat rooms in Pidgin or Empathy or a different chat program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Various people are working on doing that by manually handling the Javascript, but there is no official API or anything like that.

FWIW, I think using well-known protocols/clients is the killer feature chat is missing and would *love* to see that happen.

Answer (score 6):

On Meta Stack Overflow, there is [a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat) for XMPP support which is marked status-deferred. An unofficial [XMPP bridge](http://trac.sitepalette.com/soxmpp/) is mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63420/150419) to that question.